# How to determine the output frequency of a full-wave rectifier using an oscilloscope?

Tags: diodes, oscilloscope, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

[image: Pulsating DC]

Input frequency: 60 Hz.
Theoretically, I should get a 120 Hz output frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How often does the waveform repeat? It looks like about every four divisions, or 8 ms. The frequency is the inverse of that, or about 125 Hz.

If you want a more accurate measurement, capture several cycles and measure the period as 1/n times the duration of n cycles.

Comment: why did you use only half as a time period (π)? Unlike in half-wave, I used 16ms per period (2π).

Comment: @walter, the period is the shortest time after which the pattern repeats. (This isn't a simple sinusoid, so I don't know how you've defined "π" and "2π")